# Can I use/build custom created docker image to create another image?

Tags: docker, yaml, docker-machine, docker-image, docker-stack

I want to create an image A in one instance/server, but in that instance there is no internet connection.

So can I create an image B with all packages installed at my machine and then Push to x.x.x.x and use it in image A as the FROM tag?

It will look like :

```
FROM x.x.x.x/B:latest
RUN ***
ENTRYPOINT
```

Please suggest a correct solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes. You can do it. You can keep your image locally or push it to docker hub.

Comment: If you want something scalable, you can try to select a machine and make it a  docker registry ( server side application that stores and lets you distribute Docker images): : `$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2`

Comment: I am running from YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - of course, you can. You can use any image, including your own, to build new images.

Long answer - consider Docker `multistage build` for you purpose. This allows reduce the amount of images and the space occupied by your docker registry.

You can read more on https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

In short - you create a **single** `Dockerfile` where you define several images, based on each other. In case you don't need your base image outside from derived, this is your case. Following example will illustrate:

**Dockerfile**

```
# First create base image
FROM foo:latest as mybase # note we tag it 'mybase' 
RUN blahblah

FROM mybase  # here we derive new image, note Dockerfile is same!
RUN blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

First though, you say image A is on a server that has no internet connection. If that is true, then you can't access the built image B that you've pushed to x.x.x.x unless the x.x.x.x that you refer to is localhost.

To answer the question fully with the assumption that there's no internet:

Dockerfile B contains all the stuff you want in your base image. Build that. Then move the image to the internet-less server that you're building image A on. (To move the image, check out docker export or docker save commands and/or google 'moving a docker image from one host to another'. My initial search lead me here: https://blog.giantswarm.io/moving-docker-container-images-around/)

(note: for anyone that wants to do this and you have a internet connection, you would push image B to a repo and then pull the image straight from there in Dockerfile A which would skip the moving from host to host part.)

Then, just like you've written already, the Dockerfile for image A should have:

```
FROM imageB:latest
```

to pull from your first image. It's all pretty easy. Long story long, yes, you can build your own images and then build other images based off of that image.